# I can't run my PHP program and I received several errors

Tags: php, mysql, html, web, phpmyadmin

This is the image of the warning I got

[image]

I am new and I really want to learn PHP.

```css
<?php
 include 'mysql.conf.php';

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
  {
   $user = $_POST['user'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $select = "SELECT * FROM admin where user=$user && password=$password";
   $sql=mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
   if($sql)
   {
    echo "Login";
   }
   else
   {
    echo "Cannot Login";
   }
  }
 }

?>
```

Below is my code for the mysql.conf.php

```css
<?php
 $name = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "gasamul";

 $connect = mysql_connect($name, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());

 $db = "portfolio";
 if($connect)
 {
  $db = mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
  if($db)
  {
   //echo 'Database Connect';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'Database can\'t connect';
 }
?>
```

The name of my database is portfolio. I also named my table admin.

Comment: I think the error is too clear, it even states the solution. And btw, your query should be `SELECT * FROM admin where user='$user' && password='$password'`. Use ticks (`'`) when binding variables to queries.

Comment: Oh, and use at least [*_real_escape_strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for your submitted POST data. `$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);`

Comment: You have used updated php version where mysql_*()will not work,Update your code & use mysqli_()

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is stating clear that `mysql_*` extension is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and it is suggesting that you use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension.

Lets try the first option - `mysqli_*`. We establish first the connection to your database in `mysql.conf.php`:

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "gasamul", "portfolio");

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then, we can proceed with `logintest.php`:

```
include 'mysql.conf.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{

    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user = ? AND password = ?")){ /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY  */
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['user'], $_POST['password']); /* BIND THESE TWO VARIABLES TO THE QUERY ABOVE RESPECTIVELY; s STANDS FOR strings */
        $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
        $stmt->store_result(); /* STORE THE RESULT */
        $noofrows = $stmt->num_rows; /* GET THE NUMBER OF RESULT */
        if($noofrows > 0){ /* CHECK IF RESULT IS MORE THAN 0 */
            echo "Login";
        } else {
            echo "Cannot Login";
        }
        $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
    }

}
```

You can also check out [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for securing your password in your database.